# Count number of syllables (vowel clusters) in a string R

Tags: r

I have a variable in a df that contains sentences in Norweigan. I need to mutate a new column *no_syls* which counts how many syllables there are. The problem is that there are diphthongs (vowel clusters) which need to count as one syllable, and existing functions like from the sylcount library abort my R session (probably because the df is very very large). Does anyone know a quick and simple way to count the vowel clusters?

Below is a working example of what I'd like to make. Norwegian contains the following vowels aoeuiyæøå. Norwegian contains few to no silent vowels, those that occur, we'll just ignore.

**Edit**: a slight complication -- <ée>-sequences represent separate syllables like in the updated minimal working example below.

```
example_df <- data.frame("Tekst" = c("en", "fleire stavingar", "enda eit døme med nokre andre diftongar: øy, ei, au, osb.", "komitéen"),
                         "No_syls" = c(1, 5, 17, 4))
```

Comment: `example_df$No_syls <- stringi::stri_count_regex(example_df$Tekst, "øy|ei|au|osb|e|a|i|o|ø")` ?

Comment: That basically works, but ideally I wouldn't specify the exact diphthongs etc as this will eventually be extended to other languages...also, one complication, the sequence <ée> should be counted as two separate syllables. Does anyone have any tips on this?

Comment: We can only give some suggestions based on the question and any  data contained in it. Could you provide an example of what you are looking for, for example use case for NOR/SWE? The diphthongs could be put in a function, so the same code can be used for different languages, with the different being an argument "lang = NOR".

Comment: It's okay, the solution works well if I just control for all diphthongs. Thanks for this!